# Pulseaudio is not starting automatically

Tags: yocto, pulseaudio, xfce

I'm using yocto image with xfce desktop, here I need to audio on my usb headset for my task, I added pulseaudio but it is not getting ON automatically and without this, task is not getting fulfilled, please assist me to resolve this issue.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is pulseauto process starting automatically? Can you see it on top list?